# How to say "Not all of them do something"

Tags: sentence-construction

I wrote:

> However, not every data region is used for data extraction; some of them are employed to restrict the scope of other regions to certain portions of the page.

*Data region* is a label for a thing in the software, I want to say the purpose of all of them is not the same thing. How can I say such sentences, for another example

> **Not all of them** ? *are designated ?* to do something, some of them are supposed to do it...

I have two problem, one is that I don't know the structure to except somethings from a task, and second is that I don't know a good synonym for "designated "

Comment: Could you perhaps expand on what you find unsatisfactory in the sentence you gave (about 'data regions')?

Comment: @VictorBazarov I asked when I want to say "all of some items are not for something some of them are" How can I say that?

Comment: Try recasting your sentence in the active voice: *Some data regions {do this} while others {do something else}*  Or you could even use the passive:  *Some data regions are used {to do this} while others are used {to do that}.*

Comment: @TRomano thank you, but my original sentence is normal or not?

Comment: @TRomano my complete paragraph is *In this section, we explain the data extraction process by an example. In the previous section, we explained how the system identifies the target items using the anchors and data regions provided by the user. However, not every data region is used for data extraction; some of them are employed to restrict the scope of other regions to certain portions of the page.*

Comment: You asked "I don't know the structure to except some things from a task" and I gave you "some {do this} while others {do something else}".  You could also say "Only some {do this}; others {do something else}".  The structure is "(only) some...others".

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase it as:

However, not all data regions are used for data extraction. Some of them are employed to restrict the scope of other regions to certain portions of the page.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is using of **only** as:

> However,  <s>not every</s>  **only some** data regions are used for data extraction;  <s>some of them</s>  **others** are employed to restrict the scope of other regions to certain portions of the page.

Comment: I might use "other" if you're defining two different groups: "However only some data regions are used for data extraction; **others** are employed to restrict the scope..."